# SSH Timed out problem

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualization, kali-linux

I can't connect to my kali linux ssh server running in Virtualbox through puTTY. I didn't make any changes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, besides Port and PermitRootLogin

That's how i booted up my ssh server (openssh-server installed)

```
root@yasumi404kalimain:~# service ssh start
root@yasumi404kalimain:~# service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-06-14 13:15:13 EDT; 3s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
       man:sshd_config(5)
Process: 1694 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1695 (sshd)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
Memory: 1.2M
CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
       └─1695 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

июн 14 13:15:13 yasumi404kalimain systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
июн 14 13:15:13 yasumi404kalimain sshd[1695]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 6886.
июн 14 13:15:13 yasumi404kalimain sshd[1695]: Server listening on :: port 
6886.
июн 14 13:15:13 yasumi404kalimain systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
root@yasumi404kalimain:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1b:142c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:1b:14:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 3  bytes 778 (778.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 26  bytes 2260 (2.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 18  bytes 1038 (1.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 18  bytes 1038 (1.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And that's what I got when tried to connect.

When tried to connect via Andrax on android, being connected to the Wi-fi router which is in the same LAN as the computer.
[image: Andrax via android]

And when I also tried using puTTY in the host system of virtual machine.

[image: putty settings]
[image]

How do I solve this problem? Also, will I be able to connect to ssh server while being not in the same network, or I will need a static IP to do that?

I apologize in advance if mistake I made is silly, I'm new to infosec.
I will be happy to provide additional information/logs if needed.

UPD: I tried changing ListeningAddress to 10.0.2.15, result is still the same. (i restarted the ssh server and tried to connect)

Comment: Thus looks like a pure connectivity problem unrelated to security. I recommend to move it to superuser.com.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, I'll go there then

Comment: The virtualbox is probably not bridged or in the same subnet.Try pinging the virtual box and then the run nmap to see if you see if port 22 is open.

Comment: @VipulNair That was the problem, thanks for the answer. Though, I used port 6886 instead of 22.

Comment: Glad it worked out man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I didn't connect my Virtual machine to the bridge adapter, so I can't get access to it. I should've just add it in the VM's settings, and all started to work well!